# MailCore client stopped working in iOS7.1 (code:9)

Tags: objective-c, ios7.1, mailcore

It may not be a question per se, but anyhow, here is the problem:

I read that:

iOS7 connects fine on ports 25, 366, 110, and 143. It does not connect on ports 465, 993, and 995.
[discussed here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5325035?start=30&tstart=0)

So my emailing app that uses MailCore 1.0 to check gmail, a Mac/iOS framework for working with the e-mail protocols IMAP and SMTP [link to mailcore](https://github.com/MailCore/MailCore) stopped working since gmail imap is on 993 port.

Any workarounds? I would really appreciate.

```
CTCoreAccount *account = [[CTCoreAccount alloc] init];
BOOL success = [account connectToServer:@"imap.gmail.com"
                                   port:993
                         connectionType:CTConnectionTypeTLS
                               authType:CTImapAuthTypePlain
                                  login:appDelegate.delMyEmail
                               password:appDelegate.delPassword
                ];
```

this is what I use to connect to gmail imap, it does not connect, it returns success=NO;

account last error returns: domain:@"mailcore" - code:9

SOLVED by recompiling my app on XCode5.1

Comment: Boris, I would love to click the reopen button. But what does "not working" mean? What exactly doesn't work? Do you get a specific error? "It may not be a question per se" - make it a question and people will reopen it.

Comment: Any reason why you are using MC1 instead of 2? Legacy app?

Comment: `CTCoreAccount` has a property of `lastError`. What does it show?

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, I have to look into MC2 but if it is ports issue it wont work either, I presume. OK will look at that  error too, thanks.

Comment: Let's look at `lastError` and see what the error is. Post that.

Comment: account last error returns: domain:@"mailcore" - code:9

Comment: figure it out: I was still using XCode4.6 to work on my apps, all of them were working fine with iOS7.1, but this mailing app had  issues. I installed XCode5.1 and recompiled it, now it works fine on iOS7.1, I mean it checks e-mails and everything. Now though I need to rework all the views so they look good. Thanks Leo for helping out.

Comment: Great. Your question will be reopened soon. Make sure to post your solution and accept.

Comment: I fill reluctant answering my own questions. But I added solution to the question itself. I had a rough start on this one, if I could I would give you the right answer just for bearing with me.

Comment: No worries. Still interesting why compiling against iOS6 SDK would cause it to malfunction...

Comment: @BorisGafurov - Rather than editing the answer into the question, could you leave it as an answer and then accept that answer? That would mark the question as being resolved and remove it from the "unanswered" list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED by recompiling my app on XCode5.1